# How to find which button is pressed on the array of buttons in ios

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, ios-4.2

I have an array of buttons,I want the text on each button..to be displayed on the label..so friends,please tell me how can I achieve this

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

Simply add button in this way

```
Button.tag = i
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(MenuDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[listOfButtons addObject:Button];
```

and handle touch up event as following

```
-(IBAction)MenuDetail:(id)sender
{   
    UIButton *temp= (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger parentValue=temp.tag;
    clsMenuItem *tempMenu=[appDelegate searchMenu:parentValue];
    if(parentValue==1)
    {
            // do something
    }
    else if(parentValue==1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: hey thanks rupesh for your answer,But rupesh,I have an 2D array of buttons,I have created it in code and not in xib,so whether this will work?

Comment: Yes it works since we check the tag of button and apply action according to tag